# Prove that $\big|(|x| - |y|)\big| \leq | x - y|$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

These exercises are from Spivak's "Calculus".

> 12. v. Prove that $|x| - |y| \leq |x - y|$
>
> 12.vi. Prove that $\big|(|x| - |y|)\big| \leq |x - y|$

Here is the solution from the textbook for 12.vi.:

> Interchanging $x$ and $y$ in part (v) gives $|y| - |x| \leq |x - y|$. Combining this with part (v) yields $\big|(|x| - |y|)\big| \leq |   x - y|$.

How did they combine $|y| - |x| \leq |x - y|$ and $|x| - |y| \leq |x - y|$?

Comment: Are you sure it's not $||x|-|y||$ in part vi?

Comment: @Integrand oops, sorry about that!

Comment: $|a|$ is either $a$ or $-a$. In the same way, $||x|-|y||$ is either $|x|-|y|$ or $|y|-|x|$

Comment: Take a look at Problem 14 of the same chapter. Spivak seems to be implicitly invoking the results of that question (part (b) in particular, which says $|a| \leq b$ if and only if $-b \leq a \leq b$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a misprint. In fact take $x=4,y=5$ and you see it indeed is.

The correct statement should be $$|(|x|-|y|)|\leq |x-y|\tag{1}$$

If $a\leq b$ and $-a \leq b,$ then $|a|\leq b.$ So combining the two inequalities, you obtain $(1).$

**Edit:**

> **Lemma:** If $a \leq b$ and $-a\leq b,$ then $\max\{a,-a\}\leq b.$ Since $|a|=\max\{a,-a\},$ we obtain $|a|\leq b.$

Now let $a=|x|-|y|, b=|x-y|.$ So $a\leq b$ and $-a=-(|x|-|y|)=|y|-|x|\leq b.$ The Lemma now implies $|a| \leq b.$ In other words, $||x|-|y||\leq |x-y|.$

Comment: Could you please show the steps for combining the inequalities? I'm still not sure how those two parts can be put together.

Comment: @Iyeeke I have edited the post to elaborate.